# Python interface for presenting cursor sequence over interface image

Tags: python, image, opencv, matplotlib

I have a web interface that presents images, and on which users move their cursor. 
My system records the coordination (x,y) of the users' mouse cursor, with a timestamp for each record. The data structure looks like the example below:

| time | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0.5 | 50 | 27 |
| 1 | 23 | 135 |
| ... | ... | ... |

The interface presents about 30 images, and I have recordings of circa 180 users for each image.
So, I got 180*30 mouse location sequences (as a CSV file). 
I'm looking for the most efficient way (in Python) to 'regenerate' the user's movements so I can overview it.
Something like an interface that allows me to choose an image (among the 30 images) and a user (among the 180 users) and then shows me some sort of a video or a gif with the image that was presented to the user (as a background), and the user's movements over it (It would be even better if I could also download and save the video/gif)

As far as I know, I can build something as described above - with the interactive interface of matplotlib, but I remember it to be quite exhaustive. I also thought about using the OpenCV package, but that could be overkill, since the package will do extra work which is redundant to my use case. I assume it won't be time efficient ( For me, in the best-case scenario, that will be in real-time).
I would be happy if someone could refer me to the right interface or way to achieve that,
Thanks!

Comment: "I'm looking for the most efficient way" -- efficient in what sense? | First make something that works, then worry about optimizing it (if it's even necessary). | It would be a good idea to provide a sample input image with associated sequence of mouse locations.